# AngularJS + Parse Website Search Engine Optimization

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, angularjs, seo

I have developed a AngularJS Application together  with a Parse.com backend (only data, no business logic). They communicate over REST.

Now my problem is, that I would like to get my page indexed by google. To reach that, I somehow have to serve all my content as static pages to make sure, Google can index it.

Now I found a nice service called getseojs.com, which does nothing else than serving all contents of my website as static content.

All i had to adjust on my side was to add a Rewrite-Condition and Rule into my .htaccess file which does nothing else than forwarding all calls containing a "_escaped_fragment_=" to the getSEOjs Service.

My only problem is, that my links arent working in the static version.

The reason is quite simple:

The URL of my AngularJS application is something like www.mydomain.com/app/

Now my links look like this:

Sample Content which is working fine in normal Browsers.

The problem is, that in the static content the domain is different. It is something like:

```
http://getseojs.com/v2/sdfxsaa2/://www.mydomain.com:80/app/?_escaped_fragment_=/sample/content
```

for the same Sample Content site. When I click on a link on the static site, I get redirected to something like:

```
http://getseojs.com/v2/sdfxsaa2/://www.mydomain.com:80/app/?_escaped_fragment_=/sample/content#!/othercontent
```

instead of

```
http://getseojs.com/v2/sdfxsaa2/://www.mydomain.com:80/app/?_escaped_fragment_=/othercontent
```

Is there any way I can avoid this? Is there no other way than working with absolute URLS? But also then I got a problem, because I need the /app/ part (cause this is were my website is placed in) and between the app part and the routes I need the hashbang (#!) oder in case of googlebot the part with "?_escaped_fragment_=".

I hope someone of you can help me. I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Thanks a lot.

Greets
Marc

Comment: where you able to find a solution for this? I'm using the same service today but `fetch as google` returns a blank page screenshot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing Escaped Fragment Search with Webmaster Tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531687/testing-escaped-fragment-search-with-webmaster-tools)