# AngularJs Site getting rejected by adsense

Tags: angularjs, adsense, prerender

My website is setup on Angular served by an Apache server. I load the content dynamically onto the main page via views.

Now following is my problem :

My main aim of setting up this website was to monetize the content through google adsense. However, my content keeps on getting rejected due to "Insufficient Content". When i run a tool like feedthebot.com all i can see that the bot comes up with only 64 words. I think this might be the reason why google adsense is getting rejected for my page. I was thinking when google [or other bots] crawl the page prerender.io would return static content also back to the bots. But it seems this does not happen and only the main page gets returned.

Is there anything wrong with the setup iam using, which could be resulting in adsense rejection ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446065/google-bot-crawling-on-angularjs-site-with-html5-mode-routes

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `?_escaped_fragment_=` and `!#` to get indexed correctly.
There is a great tutorial for that [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-seo-with-prerender-io?_escaped_fragment_=tag#caveats).