# AngularJS and Google

Tags: angularjs, googlebot

I have a PHP website which is currently not using AngularJS. I'd like to change its design and while I'm at it, start using AngularJS to make a SPA website. This website contains programming tutorials, so its position in google search result is crucial. I've been searching recently to see if AngularJS can be used in that case and the most interesting post I found is this one : [Google bot crawling on AngularJS site with HTML5 Mode routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446065/google-bot-crawling-on-angularjs-site-with-html5-mode-routes)

I'd like to know if my website will still be referenced the same way if I use AngularsJS. I'll pay attention that URL stays the same, but will the Google bot be able to crawl my website the same way it does now ? I need to be sure because I don't want to loose all my traffic because Google is no longer able to crawl my site.

Answer (score 0):

Google now runs JavaScript and can index AngularJS sites.

[Source](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157)

Some caveats though: most top ranked search results are still server-rendered, so how the Google algorithm ranks your site is unclear. Also other search engines such as Bing may not be able to read your site.