# Google indexing angular js based website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexing, google-crawlers

I have a website on AngularJS and backend on NodeJs. I came to know that google can crawl and index the js based website so I entered a url on googles Fetch and render tool on webmaster

http://www.qdesq.com/moredetails/Workstation/Shared-Workstations-in-heart-of-Gurgaon?id=5662de8e06769ca61782407e

On the fetch tool google is showing the page source and not the html but on the rendering side its showing the full rendered version of the site as shown to visitors.

Now I tried to search the url on google

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Shared-Workstations-in-heart-of-Gurgaon&oq=Shared-Workstations-in-heart-of-Gurgaon&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.768j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=Shared+Workstations+in+heart+of+Gurgaon+qdesq

I found the url indexed but with unexpected text. Also on clicking the the cached version it doesnot show anything

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0_S_X5VhNe4J:www.qdesq.com/moredetails/Workstation/Shared-Workstations-in-heart-of-Gurgaon%3Fid%3D5662de8e06769ca61782407e+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in

I am not sure if the google is able to index my content.

Please enlighte on whats going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446065/google-bot-crawling-on-angularjs-site-with-html5-mode-routes

Comment: why  meta tag description  is blank, ?

Comment: I will be adding the meta tag description. But I want to understand if its indexing the rest of the content presend on website.

Comment: @user3632710 : Its not duplicate coz i have not implemented any snapshot strategy for crawling. I want to understand if google can index my site without the snapshot thing

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine now. There was some issue with my site when google indexed it. So the cache page is coming with that error. I retried the same thing with different url and its coming as expected.