# angularjs html5 mode google crawler

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, google-crawlers

i have a angularjs project with routes in html5 mode, now i tested in the google webmaster tools (view as google) but it does't work, it returns

```
<title>{{content}}</title>
```

instead of

```
<title>my title</title>
```

In the Browser it works fine

my setup in angular:

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

server config, htacces apache server:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]

 RewriteRule ^ myfolder/myfile.php [L]
```

so far i found this articles where the topic got already handled but i can't find what i did wrong or what is missing

[How do search engines deal with AngularJS applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499040/how-do-search-engines-deal-with-angularjs-applications)

[Google bot crawling on AngularJS site with HTML5 Mode routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446065/google-bot-crawling-on-angularjs-site-with-html5-mode-routes)

thanks!