# Google webmaster fetch as google issue

Tags: angularjs, seo, google-search-console

I have an angularjs app. In order to make the app Ajax Crawlable, I changed all the '#' to '#!' . When I tried the change with google webmaster tools, the results still will be redirected to the index page(Home page). my site URL is like https://www.sample.com/web/ and the rest of the URL im entering for fetch and render is like, #!/wellness . The issue is, Im always getting the rendering googlebot snapshot as the homepage(image of https://www.sample.com/web/). And the "path" column of that fetch attempt is / (The part I entered which is, #!/wellness not there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution. Though the Google web crawlers recognize the #! to escaped-fragment Fetch as Google bot requires it to be entered manually

Refer these links if someone needs help regarding an issue like this.
Below is the link to a question that exactly like mine and it has the answer

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/webmasters/fZjdyjq0n98/PZ-nlq_2RjcJ

Below link give a complete explanation on these issues

[Google bot crawling on AngularJS site with HTML5 Mode routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446065/google-bot-crawling-on-angularjs-site-with-html5-mode-routes)